# does @ModelAttribute in spring MVC have to represent an entity in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

consider the following example:

> @ModelAttribute ("personForm") PersonForm personForm

in a method, now:

1. should this PersonForm object identicle to the Person object have created as Hibernate entity?

or

2. PersonForm is just way to get input from form and access it in the controller? i.e. taking benefit of Spring MVC data binding.

Comment: Hey thanks, the next question is that what is the big benefit of using data binding, I mean we need to write a lot of classes just to get values in the controllers? I dont see any big benefit of the this thing.

Comment: You can directly get the model class from spring, use it and its lifecycle will be managed by spring.

Comment: yes but what is big benefit of using data binding other than getting form values in controllers via objects?

Comment: It doesnt matter which layer you are...you can use these objects. Thats the whole point of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 1, but 2 is right. You can use a hibernate entity for convenience, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: thanks for comment, about yoru comment "You can use a hibernate entity for convenience, but it's not a requirement" does that mean that its my choice to use hibernate entity and it doesn't have to do anything with that form classes that we create?

Comment: That's correct. If you want, you can use the same entity class as the form object. If you don't, use a different form class. A hibernate entity and an MVC ModelAttribute are unrelated things.

Comment: thanks, so is there any big benefit of using data binding other than the form data is available via object, I just dont really see this very useful

Comment: Couldn't get exactly. You mean how much is data binding useful? Or you are asking what to prefer? I prefer to reuse the entity class whenever it has similar fields as the form. Why create another class unnecessarily...

Comment: ok, I will rephrase that, 
1. so if fields in the entity class are equal to fields in the form then we can use that entity class as data binding class correct? 
2. if we are not Hibernate or and ORM, then what how data binding alone is beneficial, It seems to be like we are doing too much to get too little.

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. It could be beneficial many times. For example, you could use field level bean validation JSR-303 constraints. You could write your own class level constraints including multiple fields, like for checking retyped password to be same as the original password.

Comment: hmm, now that makes sense, its basically a cleaner way to do everything about forms isn't it?